# Do odds increase over exposure time?

Tags: mathematical-statistics

Suppose there is 1% chance of death from touching a certain spot on an outlet for 1 second. If one person touches the spot one time per year (1 sec) and second person touches the spot for 1 sec, 12 times per year. Does the second person have a higher chance of death? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to CV! If you assume that there's a fixed 1% chance that someone dies each time they touch the spot, then someone who touches it once has a 1% chance of dying & someone who sets out to touch it twelve times clearly has a larger chance. If there's more to your question than this can you please clarify?

Answer (score 1):

If we assume the trials are independent, then taking the 1% risk 12 times certainly incurs a higher chance of death than taking that 1% risk only once - nearly 12 times the chance of death.

For the person who will touch it once, the chance of death is (clearly) 1%.

For the person who will touch it 12 times, it's easier to work out their chances of survival ($0.99^{12}\approx 0.8864$), and then get the chance of death from that -- about 1 - 0.8864 = 0.1136, or 11.36%.